# numpy: what is the logic of the argmin() and argmax() functions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, argmax

I can not understand the output of `argmax` and `argmin` when use with the axis parameter. For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,4,7], [9,88,6,45], [9,76,3,4]])
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  4,  7],
       [ 9, 88,  6, 45],
       [ 9, 76,  3,  4]])
>>> a.shape
(3, 4)
>>> a.size
12
>>> np.argmax(a)
5
>>> np.argmax(a,axis=0)
array([1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> np.argmax(a,axis=1)
array([3, 1, 1])
>>> np.argmin(a)
0
>>> np.argmin(a,axis=0)
array([0, 0, 2, 2])
>>> np.argmin(a,axis=1)
array([0, 2, 2])
```

As you can see, the maximum value is the point (1,1) and the minimum one is the point (0,0). So in my logic when I run:

- `np.argmin(a,axis=0)` I expected `array([0,0,0,0])`
- `np.argmin(a,axis=1)` I expected `array([0,0,0])`
- `np.argmax(a,axis=0)` I expected `array([1,1,1,1])`
- `np.argmax(a,axis=1)` I expected `array([1,1,1])`

What is wrong with my understanding of things?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

By adding the `axis` argument, NumPy looks at the rows and columns individually. When it's not given, the array `a` is flattened into a single 1D array.

`axis=0` means that the operation is performed *down* the columns of a 2D array `a` in turn.

For example `np.argmin(a, axis=0)` returns the index of the minimum value in each of the four columns. The minimum value in each column is shown in   **bold** below:

```
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  4,  7],  # 0
       [ 9, 88,  6, 45],  # 1
       [ 9, 76,  3,  4]]) # 2

>>> np.argmin(a, axis=0)
array([0, 0, 2, 2])
```

On the other hand, `axis=1` means that the operation is performed *across* the rows of `a`.

That means `np.argmin(a, axis=1)` returns `[0, 2, 2]` because `a` has three rows. The index of the minimum value in the first row is 0, the index of the minimum value of the second and third rows is 2:

```
>>> a
#        0   1   2   3
array([[ 1,  2,  4,  7],
       [ 9, 88,  6, 45],
       [ 9, 76,  3,  4]])

>>> np.argmin(a, axis=1)
array([0, 2, 2])
```

Comment: what about axis=-1 ?

Comment: got it, it must be last dimension, in here for 2d it is column i guess

Comment: How would axis work on a 3D array, where you can have `axis=0`, `axis=1`, or `axis=2`?

Comment: Thank you. I see that if I gave `argmax([0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])`, it will return 1 (one hot encodeing). So I am confused as argmax is supposed to return index of min or max not the number that corresponds to the max index in this case.

Answer (score 5):

The `np.argmax` function by default works [along the flattened array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), unless you specify an axis. To see what is happening you can use `flatten` explicitly:

```
np.argmax(a)
>>> 5

a.flatten()
>>>> array([ 1,  2,  4,  7,  9, 88,  6, 45,  9, 76,  3,  4])
             0   1   2   3   4   5
```

I've numbered the indices under the array above to make it clearer. Note that indices are numbered from zero in `numpy`.

In the cases where you specify the axis, it is also working as expected:

```
np.argmax(a,axis=0)
>>> array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

This tells you that the largest value is in row `1` (2nd value), for each column along `axis=0` (down). You can see this more clearly if you change your data a bit:

```
a=np.array([[100,2,4,7],[9,88,6,45],[9,76,3,100]])
a
>>> array([[100,   2,   4,   7],
           [  9,  88,   6,  45],
           [  9,  76,   3, 100]])

np.argmax(a, axis=0)
>>> array([0, 1, 1, 2])
```

As you can see it now identifies the maximum value in row 0 for column 1, row 1 for column 2 and 3 and row 3 for column 4.

There is a useful guide to `numpy` indexing in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Answer (score 4):

As a side note: if you want to find the coordinates of your maximum value in the full array, you can use

```
a=np.array([[1,2,4,7],[9,88,6,45],[9,76,3,4]])
>>> a
[[ 1  2  4  7]
 [ 9 88  6 45]
 [ 9 76  3  4]]

c=(np.argmax(a)/len(a[0]),np.argmax(a)%len(a[0]))
>>> c
(1, 1)
```

Comment: Or simply: `np.unravel_index(np.argmax(a), a.shape)`

Answer (score 3):

```
""" ....READ THE COMMENTS FOR CLARIFICATION....."""

import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,4,7], [9,88,6,45], [9,76,3,4]])

"""np.argmax(a) will give index of max value in flatted array of given matrix """
>>np.argmax(a)
5

"""np.argmax(a,axis=0) will return list of indexes of  max value column-wise"""
>>print(np.argmax(a,axis=0))
[1,1,1,1]

"""np.argmax(a,axis=1) will return list of indexes of  max value row-wise"""
>>print(np.argmax(a,axis=1))
[3,1,1]

"""np.argmin(a) will give index of min value in flatted array of given matrix """
>>np.argmin(a)
0

"""np.argmin(a,axis=0) will return list of indexes of  min value column-wise"""
>>print(np.argmin(a,axis=0))
[0,0,2,2]

"""np.argmin(a,axis=0) will return list of indexes of  min value row-wise"""
>>print(np.argmin(a,axis=1))
[0,2,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

The axis in the argmax function argument, refers to the axis along which the array will be sliced.

In another word, `np.argmin(a,axis=0)` is effectively the same as `np.apply_along_axis(np.argmin, 0, a)`, that is to find out the minimum location for these sliced vectors along the axis=0.

Therefore in your example, `np.argmin(a, axis=0)` is `[0, 0, 2, 2]` which corresponding to values of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` on respective columns

Comment: Thank you sir.  I upvote but I accept an other answer which is too clear for my way of understanding things.